# How to pass a variable into catch statement in AWS Step Functions

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I develop a very simple workflow in AWS Step Functions like the below picture.

[image]

`CreateNewItem` function creates a new record in Dynamo DB, then if it fails, the `Create NewItemFail` function calls.

`CreateNewItemFail` function sends an email including information about the data the first function tried to insert into Dynamo DB.

However, I have no idea how to throw a variable into the failer function.

This is the handler function code of the `CreateNewItem` function.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({
    region: "ap-northeast-1",
})
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
const table = "ItemTable";

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    const item = {
        id: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        name: 'hello',
    }

    try {

        //
        // Insert data(item) into Dynamo DB here.
        //

    } catch(e) {
        const createItemError = new Error('Insert data error');
        createItemError.name = "CreateItemError";

        // here, I would like to know how to pass the `item` variable. 
        throw createItemError;
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

The `CreateNewItemFail` function's input is this.

```json
{
  "Error": "CreateItemError",
  "Cause": "{\"errorType\":\"CreateItemError\",\"errorMessage\":\"Insert data error\",\"trace\":[\"CreateItemError: Insert data error\",\"    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:147:28)\",\"    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)\"]}"
}
```

Comment: You can send vars to next status with OutputPath, not but the Lambda function itself. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-example.html